# Merging Cells in Excel from an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, merge

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: **Cell B2: Start Date** and **Cell B3: End Date**

Example: 
B2 --> 01/01/2019 
B3 --> 01/03/2019

[image: Example Excel]

I have an array with the week numbers between these two dates. Example array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), including the last week of February(week 9). I'm Working on a Planning excel that's why I'm considerating also **week 9** (We had some issues in the last post, that's why I'm explaining it)

Here is my code for obtaining this array

```
Sub FillCal()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim StartDate As Range, EndDate As Range
Dim NoOfWeeks As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Foglio1")
    Set StartDate = .Range("B2")
    Set EndDate = .Range("B3")
End With

NoOfWeeks = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((EndDate.Value2 - StartDate.Value2) / 7, 0)

ReDim arr(1 To NoOfWeeks)
For i = 1 To NoOfWeeks
    arr(i) = i
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is: Starting from Cell  **D4**, put the 1st value of the array **arr** in it and merge cells **E4** and **F4** with it(so cells **D4, E4, F4** merged with value **1**), put next value of the array(in this case Cell **G4** and value **2**) in it and merge the 2 other cells on the right so it would be Cells **G4, H4, I4** with value **2** and so on... till last value of the array (Sorry for bad English I will attach a photo for better understanding)

Here is the output that I would like to obtain:

[image: Better understanding]

So Its basically: merge every 3 cells.

Since an user asked for it, here is how I try to merge...

```
i = wks.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Row
Set rngMerge = wks.Range("A3:XZ3" & i) ' Find last row in column A

With wks

checkAgain:
For Each rngCell In rngMerge

    If rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value And IsEmpty(rngCell) =        False Then

        Range(rngCell, rngCell.Offset(0, 1)).Merge
        rngCell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        rngCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        rngCell.BorderAround ColorIndex:=1

        GoTo checkAgain
    End If

Next
End With
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself to make it work? No offense, but it seems like the community is slowly building the code for you (looking at your former question). You should at least try yourself. And when you get stuck you can get help regarding an issue/error.

Comment: You'd never look stupid posting code you trying yourself, and certainly not when you new to VBA. About the code, you can put that into your question, the same way you did with the other code.

Comment: Yes i did it now. Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting for `D4` as a "given", point and merging any 3 cells as far as there is something in the array, this is what I have managed to build:

[image]

This is the code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Worksheets(1).Cells.Delete

    Dim myCellToStart As Range
    Set myCellToStart = Worksheets(1).Range("D4")

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

    Dim myVar As Variant
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = myCellToStart

    For Each myVar In myArray

        Set myCell = Worksheets(1).Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(, 2))

        myCell.Merge
        BorderMe myCell
        myCell = myVar

        Set myCell = myCell.Offset(, 1)

    Next myVar

End Sub
```

The "trick" is to define the range to be merged correctly. It is carried out with `Set myCell = Worksheets(1).Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(, 2))` and with `Set myCell = myCell.Offset(, 1)` to mark the new start.

And this is the "Bordering" function:

```
Public Sub BorderMe(myRange As Range)

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = 7 To 10 '7 to 10 are the magic numbers for xlEdgeLeft etc
        With myRange.Borders(cnt)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If I can ask for more explanation `Worksheets(1).Cells.Delete` can I give it a range of Cells? Because I usually use `.Clear` --> but it does not cancel the width of the Columns(I put some custom width to the column to make them easier to read).

Comment: @ChangeWorld - it was put just to reset the worksheet. In general, giving a range is quite ok - `Worksheets(1).Range("A5:D10").Delete`

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use an array, since you are assigning `NoOfWeeks` as a variable;

Just replace this portion of your first code...

```
ReDim arr(1 To NoOfWeeks)
For i = 1 To NoOfWeeks
    arr(i) = i
Next i
```

With this code...

```
x = 4

For i = 1 To NoOfWeeks
    With Cells(3, x)
        .Value = i
        .Resize(, 3).Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    End With
    x = x + 3
Next i
```